# how to create draggable scrolling bottom sheet inside google maps scaffold in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

I want to create a draggable scrolling bottom sheet like this!

[here is the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYPjV.jpg)

there will be a button on the top left to go back, there will be a button on the top left to go back, and there is a draggable bottom sheet should I use the stack?
please give me a hint if you have the best way to approach this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below plugin.

[Snapping sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/snapping_sheet)

Snapping sheet provides a highly customizable sheet widget that snaps to different vertical & horizontal positions

Comment: This project is archived.

Answer (score 0):

This is exact what you need, [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("SlidingUpPanelExample"),
    ),
    body: SlidingUpPanel(
      panel: Center(
        child: Text("This is the sliding Widget"),
      ),
      body: /* place your google map here */
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This project seems to be dead.